# What does mean this notation $q \mid k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, divisibility

Here is two numbers $q$ and $k$. Tell me please what does mean this notation $q \mid k$? Are they relatively prime or something ?

Comment: The relation to the primes : A number $p>1$ is called a prime number, if $m|p$ with $m>0$ is only true for $m=1$ and $m=p$, in other words, the only divisors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$.

Comment: Since $1$ and $p$ are always divisors, they are called trivial divisors. So, you can also say : A number $p$ is prime, if it does not have a non-trivial divisor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The notation means : $q$ divides $k$ ; There is an integer $m$ with $qm=k$.

Comment: Alternatively: $\frac{k}{q}$ is an integer.

Comment: @Arthur No; the usual definition covers also the case $0\mid 0$, which yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $q$ divides $k$, or $k$ is divisible by $q$. Add a little slash and it negates that meaning: $q \nmid k$ means $q$ does *not* divide $k$.

For example: $3 \mid 1728$, $3 \nmid 1729$.

They are not relatively prime, unless $q = 1$ or $-1$. In fact, if $q \mid k$ then $\gcd(q, k) = |q|$.